# How many 747-200 are still in service?

Tags: aviation-history, boeing-747

I'm wondering how many 747-200's are still in service?
I know for sure [Rolls Royce is using one for testing purposes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDaagO2iYdM).
[And the one from the US Forces.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doElXk4faRQ)

- Are there any civilian operated ones left?
- Does somebody have photos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running the numbers from [RedGrittyBrick's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9341/946), there appear to be 36 active 747-200s out of 393 built (according to Wikipedia). Of the 36, 9 are passenger planes, 22 freight (including 6 converted from passenger planes, marked <sup>*</sup>), 3 combi (passenger and freight), and the two VC-25As ("Air Force One").

The active aircraft are as follows, with tail numbers included so you can look for photos.

- Aerospace One: 1 freight (SX-ASO), 1 combi (SX-ASC)
- AHS Air International: 1 freight (AP-BIO)
- Cargo Air Lines: 1 combi (4X-ICM)
- Caspian Airlines: 1 freight (EP-CQA)
- Iran Air: 3 passenger (EP-IAG, EP-IAH, EP-IAI), 1 combi (EP-ICD)
- Jet Star: 1 freight (ER-BBS)
- Kabo Air: 3 passenger (5N-DKB, 5N-JRM, 5N-MAD)
- Kalitta Air: 2 passenger (N715CK, N793CK), 4 freight (N704CK, N746CK, N794CK,<sup>*</sup> N795CK<sup>*</sup>)
- Kam Air: 1 freight (4L-TZS)
- Midex Airlines: 3 freight (A6-MDG, A6-MDH, A6-MDI)
- Orient Thai Airlines: 1 passenger (HS-UTC)
- Rayyan Air<sup>**</sup>: 2 freight (AP-BKI, AP-BKS<sup>*</sup>)
- Saha Airlines: 2 freight (EP-SHB, EP-SHH)
- Saudi Arabian Airlines: 1 freight (HZ-AIU)
- United States Air Force: 2 VC-25A (82-8000, 92-9000)
- Uni-Top Airlines: 3 freight (B-2448,<sup>*</sup> B-2450,<sup>*</sup> B-2462)
- Veteran Avia: 1 freight (EK74799<sup>*</sup>)
- Vision Air International: 1 freight (AP-BIV)

<sup>*</sup> Built as passenger and converted to freight.
<sup>**</sup> Not to be confused with Ryanair! :-)

There are also several stored aircraft, including the Rolls-Royce test plane you mention in the question.

---

Thanks to [fooot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/1696/fooot) for explaining that BSF denotes "[Boeing Special Freighter](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/FR-2012-08-08/html/2012-18627.htm)", a passenger plane [converted to freight use](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/3064296/).

Comment: What did they do to the other ones?

Comment: @Firee Scrapped or in storage.

Answer (score 8):

> **How many 747-200 are still in Service?**

If you search [Airfleets.net](http://www.airfleets.net/listing/b747-1.htm) and, for all pages, add up the aircraft marked as active, you will get an answer.

[image]

> **Are there any Civilian Operated ones left?**

If you mean non-military, the above method should tell you.

If you mean non-airline, I don't know how to find out easily. RR's [N-787RR](https://www.google.com/search?q=N-787RR+747+image&es_sm=122&tbm=isch) was [hard to find](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b747-21966.htm) at Airfleets.net.

> **Does somebody have Photos?**

Almost certainly yes, I'd just Google the registration number. e.g. [EP-SHB](https://www.google.com/search?q=ep-shb+747&source=lnms&tbm=isch). They'll mostly be copyright protected of course.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022 (And what I'm aware):

Fly Pro: 1 freight (ER-BAR)

Fars Air Qeshm: (EP-FAA & EP-FAB)

Iran Air: (EP-ICD)

Kam Air: 1 freight (4L-TZS)

Fly Pro Cargo: 1 freight (ER-BAT)

Iran Air Force: 1+ Military (5-8106)

United States Air Force: 2 VC-25A (82-8000, 92-9000)

E4B: 4 Military

GeoSky: 2 freight (4L-GEN, 4L-GEO)

Aerostan: 2 Freight (EX-47001, EX-47002)

Sources:

planespotters.net/operators/Boeing/747/747-200

I did remove some that were on the list as they are stored IRL but stated as active on Planespotters.net.

Comment: Source, please?

Comment: https://www.planespotters.net/operators/Boeing/747/747-200

Here!

Edit: I did remove some that were on the list as they are stored IRL but stated as active on Planespotters.net.

Comment: For those who suggest edits to this post: without something authoritative (i.e. a source -- in other words a link to something stating that "this" 747-200 is no longer operating, for instance), suggested edits will probably be rejected, because without a source to check, such an edit is indistinguishable from vandalism.  If you have a document that demonstrates the truth of your edit, then please ***incorporate*** within your edit the link to that source, and it will probably be approved.